# Difference between addAttributeToFilter and addFieldToFilter in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

What's the difference between addAttributeToFilter and addFieldToFilter in Magento? I created a custom attribute YES/NO. But neither of them is working for me when I tried to pull a product collection. Its not filtering anything.

```
    $Products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $Products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $Products->addFieldToFilter('amazon_listed',1);
    $Products->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $Products->load();
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**addFieldToFilter** will filter the products based on columns in the database from the table catalog_product_entity.

**addAttributeToFilter** will filter the products based on the attributes that you've included in your collection.

In your case you must use **addAttributeToFilter** like this:

```
$Products->addAttributeToFilter('amazon_listed',array('eq' => 1));
$Products->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
```

Answer (score 7):

> **addAttributeToFilter()** is used to filter EAV collections.
>
> **addFieldToFilter()** is used to filter Non-EAV collections.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue,

use addAttributeToFilter() method and try to set "Used in Product Listing" = Yes for your attribute on Edit attribute page in the Admin panel.

Hope it will help.